# Bundle Setup within Codeception

Tags: symfony, codeception

I tried to setup codeception for my Symfony2 project which already has 4 working bundles and their PHPUnit testcases. Now I wanted to add codeception Testcases, especially for acceptance tests, but when I "bootstrapped" codeception I found all the generated code within my main structure. Since my application is already organized in bundles I wanted to keep the concept as well for my testcases. Especially since I already have my PHPUnit testcases within my bundles. The official s2 codeception does not really cover this. So for me some questions arise:

1. How to setup codeception that it works within my bundles
2. How can I ran with one command all my existing PHPUnit testcases AND my codeception testcases?

Answer (score 2):

I just set that up in a similar way.

codeception has a -c switch that will do what you need, i.e.:

```
vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap src/Acme/ExampleBundle
```

and then:

```
vendor/bin/codecept run -c src/Acme/ExampleBundle
```

I don't know about your 2nd question. At least for Unit tests, converting them to Codeception tests was trivial, especially since my tests all inhert from an abstract class, so it took maybe 10 lines of change there, mostly setup stuff.

Comment: You could also add the following lines to the root `codeception.yml` file instead of having to specify the `-c` flag each time:
`include:
  - src/Acme/ExampleBundle`
then just run `vendor/bin/codecept run` as normal. It will locate the bundle's `codeception.yml` config and include all the tests in the same run.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom That doesen't work because the Symfony2-Module is looking for the bootstrap.php.cache-file which is still in the root-folder of your symfony2-app! My solution for this is to create a link in your bundle to your app/ folder! than it gonna work!

In {your-root}/src/{your-app}/{your-bundle}:

```
ln -s ../../../app .
```